# Can I keyframe the position of an image texture node on the surface of a model?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, node-editor, keyframes, shader-nodes

I'm trying to keyframe eyes on a model but the eyes are image textures on a surface. Moving the surface that they're on doesn't work. I just need a way to move the eyes (images) on the surface. changing the position of the original 3 images (alb, nrm, and tcl images) without editing the images so I can animate them

Eyeballs wont work because they wont fit the eye holes.

Here is a screenshot.

Let me know if more info is needed.

[image: need to move the location of the eyes]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can animate and keyframe image texture movement.
First you need to create a UV node and connect it to your image nodes. That way all of them will use the same coordinates. After that you can add a Vector math node between those two and change the x and y values to move the eyeballs.
Once you are able to move them using those values, you can also add keyframes to them.

[image]

Comment: ok i did this and looked in the graph editor to adjust the curves but they werent there. is there another way to modify the keyframe animation?

Comment: The node called Normal has 2 balls. You can move the top one to move the eyes and add keyframes to it

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways you can animate movement of a texture on a plane. Here is the most direct:

[image: technique for animating the movement of a texture]

The plane is already UV unwrapped.

Change the image mode from "Repeat" to "Clip".

Set your keyframes on the X and Y values in the Mapping node.  Changing these values moves the effective position of the image on the UV Map.